# Status of Expired In-App Subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

For an Android app, I would like to find out whether a user has consumed their free trial period.  Is there any way I can determine that information from in-app subscription information?

Comment: In order for others to better understand your problem, a more definitive explanation of the problem and expected outcome will help immensly

Answer (score 0):

a) Use backend, for example in the login. If the user makes a log-in check in backend if the user trial has expired or not.

b) Save in Shared Preferences a value, for example the number of times that user opens the app, or the first date he opened the app (everytime he opens the app check that today - firstTime <= TrialDays.

etc.

There are so many approaches, think about it.